# Rust is not generating .profraw files for any project

Tags: rust, llvm, code-coverage, rust-cargo

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://marco-c.github.io/2020/11/24/rust-source-based-code-coverage.html) to be able to have source code coverage for a project in Rust.

I did the following:

1. Installed **grcov**

```
     cargo install grcov
```

2. Added **llvm-tools-preview**

```
     rustup component add llvm-tools-preview
```

3. Set my **RUSTFLAGS** variable to **"-Zinstrument-coverage"**

```
     set RUSTFLAGS="-Zinstrument-coverage"
```

4. I build my project

```
    cargo build
```

5. Set my `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE` variable to: `"test-%p-%m.profraw"`

```
    set LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="test-%p-%m.profraw"
```

6. Run my tests with

```
    cargo test
```

But no .profraw files appears, I only have the following:

[image: file tree]

Am I missing some extra configuration?

Here is my environment information:
cargo 1.57.0 (b2e52d7ca 2021-10-21)
release: 1.57.0
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
os: Windows 10.0.18363 (Windows 10 Enterprise) [64-bit]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: According to the page you linked, `-Zinstrument-coverage` requires the nightly compiler.

Comment: Thanks you, i will try with nightly compiler

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing similar behavior with rust 1.61 nightly on windows.  I noticed warning messages stating `""test-%p-%m.profraw""` could not be written.  In my case, the fix was to change how I set the `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE` environment variable.  If I set it like:

`set LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=test-%p-%m.profraw` *without* the wrapping quotation marks and re-run my tests, the .profraw files are generated.

Your mileage may vary.  I had the same issue with the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable where I had to remove the quotes for it to even compile.

Another noteworthy thing I encountered with 1.61 is a warning that `-Zinstrument-coverage` is deprecated in favor of `-Cinstrument-coverage`.